# Error adding a key value pair to the dictionary of artists

Tags: python, json, dictionary

The API of the [Artsy](https://developers.artsy.net/v2/start) project provides information about some artists, their works, exhibitions.

I'm trying to make a get request to all artists by their id from a file dataset_24476_4.txt

Example of a string from a file

**4d8b92a44eb68a1b2c000328**

An example of the answer can be found at the [link](https://pastebin.com/trprET9T)

The python interpreter throws the error `name = r['name'] KeyError: 'name'`, but `print(r["name"])` works correctly

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import requests

client_id = '---'
client_secret = '---'

r = requests.post("https://api.artsy.net/api/tokens/xapp_token",
    data = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret
    }
).json()

token = r["token"]

headers = {
    "X-Xapp-Token" : token
}

artists = {}

# test get request 
r = requests.get(
    f"https://api.artsy.net/api/artists/4d8b92b34eb68a1b2c0003f4", 
    headers=headers
).json()

print(r)

with open('dataset_24476_4.txt') as file:
    for num in file:
        num = num[:-1]
        
        r = requests.get(
            f"https://api.artsy.net/api/artists/{num}", 
            headers=headers
        ).json()
        
        name = r['name']
        birthday = r['birthday']
        print(name, birthday)
        
        artists.update({ 
            name : birthday,
        })

print(sorted(
    artists.items(), 
    key=lambda x: (
        x[1], 
        x[0]
    )
))
```

Comment: you use `r['name']` in a loop. in one of the iterations your are missing this key. just check if the key exists before trying to access it.

Comment: There really is no key, because I'm trying to add it to an empty dictionary now

Comment: you do `name = r['name']` which means `r` must have a key named `name`

Comment: Now I understand you. 

In r there is a key name 
('create_at': '2010-08-23T14:15:30+00:00', ' updated': '2022-02-03T11:47:55+00:00', 'name': "Andy Warhol", "sortable name": "Andy Warhol", "gender": "man" ...)

Comment: yes, and in your code you loop over several websites. At least one of them return an `r` without a key named `name` on it

Comment: Yes, one of the queries does not produce a result:(

Thank you for your help :)